# kdenlive won't automatically enable audio on clips

Tags: kdenlive

I've recently started using Kdenlive and am continually frustrated by its apparent default behaviour of not using audio from my clips.

I add stills and short clips to the timeline, but the audio in the clips is ignored.

[image: No audio in timeline]

If I go ahead and render the whole video is silenced.

I have to manually go through each track and click on "Restore audio".

[image: Audio restored]

I can't even "select all" and do it *en masse*, I have to do it all manually.

I cannot find an option anywhere in the settings that has any effect on this behaviour.

Can anyone help?

```
$ apt show kdenlive
Package: kdenlive
Version: 4:22.08.3-1~ubuntu22.04.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This was frustrating to me too but I finally figured out that if you add images and videos in one drag it will ignore the audio of the videos (probably because images don't have audio).
So what you need to do as you are building up your timeline, don't combine stills and videos in the same drag operation. if you want to have 3 stills  followed by 2 videos and then some more stills, drag the 3 stills, then drag the 2 videos (and it will immediately become apparent that the audio portion of these videos is there), then the rest of the stills in the 3rd drag.

I don't know if this is the best way to do it in KdenLive but it works.
I Hope the developers would improve this or someone would explain how to better do this

Comment: This is what I've ended up doing.